# How do I change Rails environment on OpenShift?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

I'm trying to set up this application to run in Development mode but the default environment on Openshift seems to be Production or Deployment

I tried to change gems versions on the server and it throwed:

> You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
>   your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
>   updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
>
> If this is a development machine, remove the Gemfile freeze 
>   by running `bundle install --no-deployment`.

But I didnt manage to find a way to change my environment. When I hit `rhc env list my_app` nothing happens

How do I change my environment on Openshift so everything I do is on Development mode?

Answer (score 1):

**To change ENV of app**

```
#in my case, APPNAME: files

rhc env set APPLICATION_ENV=development --app APPNAME
rhc app restart APPNAME
```